# Merging two separate GatsbyJS starter themes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am basically trying to integrate the gatsby-starter-ghost blog template with another static site template called gatsby-serif-theme.

I am struggling with a few things.

1. How can I integrate two different gatsby-config.js files together? I
   am getting quite a few errors here (I have pasted the consolidated
   gatsby-config.js file contents below in this E-mail).
2. I am able to stitch together the package.json files from both projects without much issue. Also posted the contents of package.json below.
3. I was also able to create a new folder called “Blog” under the
       src/pages folder of my existing static site for gatsby-serif-themes
4. Both the themes have their own schema inside GraphQL.

   Is there a prescribed method to go about doing this integration?

The number of configuration changes to stitch together both the themes can be quite challenging especially when you have configuration files such as gatsby-config.js, gatsby-browser.js and gatsby-node.js, netlify.toml in both the templates etc.

Any pointers in the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Error:

> error We encountered an error while trying to load your site's gatsby-config. TypeError: Cannot destructure property apiUrl of 'undefined' or 'null'.

```js
/** gatsbyconfig.js **/

const guid = process.env.NETLIFY_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID;
const path = require(path)

const config = require(./src/utils/siteConfig)
const generateRSSFeed = require(./src/utils/rss/generate-feed)

let ghostConfig

try {
    ghostConfig = require(./.ghost)
} catch (e) {
    ghostConfig = {
        production: {
            apiUrl: process.env.GHOST_API_URL,
            contentApiKey: process.env.GHOST_CONTENT_API_KEY,
        },
    }
} finally {
    const { apiUrl, contentApiKey } = process.env.NODE_ENV === development ? ghostConfig.development : ghostConfig.production

    if (!apiUrl || !contentApiKey || contentApiKey.match(/<key>/)) {
        throw new Error(GHOST_API_URL and GHOST_CONTENT_API_KEY are required to build. Check the README.) // eslint-disable-line
    }
}

module.exports = {
    siteMetadata: {
        title: ‘Technovature Software’,
        description: ‘Next Generation Innovation’,
        contact: {
            phone: ‘+91 7013175234’,
            email: ‘info@technovature.com’,
            address: ‘Hyderabad’,
        },
        menuLinks: [{
                name: ‘Services’,
                link: ‘/services’,
            }, {
                name: ‘OUR WORK’,
                link: ‘/work’,
            }, {
                name: ‘About’,
                link: ‘/about’,
            }, {
                name: ‘Blog’,
                link: ‘/blog’,
            }, {
                name: ‘Testimonials’,
                link: ‘/testimonials’,
            }, {
                name: ‘Contact’,
                link: ‘/contact’,
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        ‘gatsby-plugin-sass’,
        ‘gatsby-transformer-json’,
        ‘gatsby-transformer-remark’,
        ‘gatsby-plugin-react-helmet’,
        {
            resolve: ‘gatsby-source-filesystem’,
            options: {
                path: ${dirname}/src/pages,
                name: ‘pages’,
            },
        }, {
            resolve: ‘gatsby-source-filesystem’,
            options: {
                path: ${dirname}/src/data,
                name: ‘data’,
            },
        }, {
            resolve: ‘gatsby-source-filesystem’,
            options: {
                path: ${__dirname}/src/images,
                name: ‘images’,
            },
        }, {
        resolve: ‘gatsby-plugin-google-analytics’,
        options: {
            trackingId: guid ? guid : ‘UA-XXX-1’,
            // Puts tracking script in the head instead of the body
            head: false,
            },
        },
        gatsby-plugin-sharp,
        gatsby-transformer-sharp,
        {
            resolve: gatsby-source-ghost,
            options:
                process.env.NODE_ENV === development
                    ? ghostConfig.development
                    : ghostConfig.production,
        },
        /** Utility Plugins */ 
        { resolve: gatsby-plugin-ghost-manifest, options: { short_name: config.shortTitle, start_url: /, background_color: config.backgroundColor, theme_color: config.themeColor, display: minimal-ui, icon: static/${config.siteIcon}, query: { allGhostSettings { edges { node { title description } } } }, }, }, { resolve: gatsby-plugin-feed, options: { query: { allGhostSettings { edges { node { title description } } } }, feeds: [ generateRSSFeed(config), ], }, }, { resolve: gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap, options: { query: { allGhostPost { edges { node { id slug updated_at created_at feature_image } } } allGhostPage { edges { node { id slug updated_at created_at feature_image } } } allGhostTag { edges { node { id slug feature_image } } } allGhostAuthor { edges { node { id slug profile_image } } } }, mapping: { allGhostPost: { sitemap: posts, }, allGhostTag: { sitemap: tags, }, allGhostAuthor: { sitemap: authors, }, allGhostPage: { sitemap: pages, }, }, exclude: [ /dev-404-page, /404, /404.html, /offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback, ], createLinkInHead: true, }, }, gatsby-plugin-force-trailing-slashes, gatsby-plugin-offline,
    ],
};
```

```
/** package.json file contents **/


{
  "name": "gatsby-serif-theme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Robert Austin <rob@jugglerdigital.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "now-build": "npm run build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js --cache",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tryghost/helpers": "1.1.3",
    "@tryghost/helpers-gatsby": "1.0.6",
    "cheerio": "1.0.0-rc.3",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
    "core-js": "^3.1.2",
    "gatsby": "^2.0.33",
    "gatsby-awesome-pagination": "0.3.4",
    "gatsby-image": "2.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap": "1.0.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-feed": "2.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-force-trailing-slashes": "1.0.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "2.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "2.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.0.14",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.0.7",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "2.0.37",
    "gatsby-source-ghost": "3.3.2",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "2.1.19",
    "lodash": "4.17.11",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.12",
    "gatsby-transformer-json": "^2.1.6",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.1.15",
    "google-map-react": "^1.1.4",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react": "^16.5.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.5.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-ghost": "0.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2"
  }
}
```

```js
/** gatsby-node.js file contents **/

const path = require('path');

// Create pages from markdown files
exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(
      graphql(
        `
          query {
            services: allMarkdownRemark(
              filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/services/" } }
              sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
            ) {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                  frontmatter {
                    path
                    title
                    date(formatString: "DD MMMM YYYY")
                  }
                  excerpt
                }
              }
            }
            team: allMarkdownRemark(
              filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/team/" } }
              sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
            ) {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                  frontmatter {
                    path
                    title
                    date(formatString: "DD MMMM YYYY")
                  }
                  excerpt
                }
              }
            }
            testimonials: allMarkdownRemark(
              filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/testimonials/" } }
              sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
            ) {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                  frontmatter {
                    path
                    title
                    date(formatString: "DD MMMM YYYY")
                  }
                  excerpt
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `,
      ).then((result) => {
        result.data.services.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
          const component = path.resolve('src/templates/service.js');
          createPage({
            path: node.frontmatter.path,
            component,
            context: {
              id: node.id,
            },
          });
        });
        result.data.team.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
          const component = path.resolve('src/templates/team.js');
          createPage({
            path: node.frontmatter.path,
            component,
            context: {
              id: node.id,
            },
          });
        });
        result.data.testimonials.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
          const component = path.resolve('src/templates/testimonial.js');
          createPage({
            path: node.frontmatter.path,
            component,
            context: {
              id: node.id,
            },
          });
        });
        resolve();
      }),
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: When I run 'gatsby develop' at the terminal console, I get the below error.

error We encountered an error while trying to load your site's gatsby-config.


  TypeError: Cannot destructure property `apiUrl` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

Comment: Is `GHOST_API_URL` set in `.env.development`?

Comment: check the `./ghost` file or directory at your root. The error is saying it couldn't find a `development` or `production` export from there.